# Почему JVM не распознаёт версию?

Tags: java, swing

java -version 1.8. javac - version 13.

Написал GUI программу в IntelliJIdea. 
Для создания jar-файла исправил настройки:

В Project Structure -> Project-> Project Language Level ->8 Lambdas.

В Project Structure -> Project-> Project SDK -> corretto 1.8

При этом пришлось поправить расположение графических элементов (из-за отличий версий)

Сделал jar-файл. Отправляю на другой компьютер. На нём: java -version 1.8,  javac - не установлен. Всё работает нормально. Но если запускаю эту программу на своём компьютере (установлена java 13) графические элементы сдвинуты из-за того, что в 13 java другая толщина рамки на окне (Frame). Получается, что моя JVM распознаёт jar-файл как 13 версию, а не 1.8. Как указать моей JVM, что этоn jar-файл версии 1.8?

Причём если запускаю jar из IDE, то всё работает нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй просто версию своей JVM поменять с 13 на  8

Comment: Как это сделать? Плохо в этом ориентируюсь.

Comment: https://poweruser.guru/questions/262757/изменение-текущей-версии-java-в-windows Я сам точно не помню но вот тут такой вопрос задавали

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]